# Javascript variable as html tag name

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function genbox()
{
var i;
var myarray = new Array();
myarray[0] = "name";
myarray[1] = "dob";
myarray[2] = "email";
for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
{
document.write('<input name="' + myarray[i] + '"/>');
}
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button"  value="create" onclick="genbox();">
</body>
</html>
```

Old:I want the textbox name as the values of the array such as name, dob etc. but all i'm getting is 3 textboxes with the same name "myarray[i]". Please help me.

Okay, Here we go, I'm pretty new to js. After clicking the button it creates 3 textboxes, but, the button disappears, What should I do to keep the button alive???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this line in the loop instead:

```
document.write('<input name="' + myarray[i] + '"/>');
```

Working jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8uPVT/1/).

Answer (score 5):

You can't insert JavaScript variables inside a string and expect the interpreter to extract its value (as some languages do, like PHP). Build your string using concatenation instead:

```
"<input name='" + myArray[i] + "'/>"
```

Comment: thank you .. but it seems, the double quotes are messing up .. :(

Comment: @user2122914 I added single quotes around each attribute value to conform to stricter HTML specifications, but in principle you can remove them: `"<input name=" + myArray[i] + "/>"`. An alternative would be to swap single and double quotes: `'<input name="' + myArray[i] + '"/>'`

Answer (score 0):

You should go through some basic tutorials about javascript, try http://www.codecademy.com/

Here's the code, however you shouldn't add html with document.write, there are other, better methods to do it.

```
    var i,
        myarray = ["name", "dob", "email"];

    for (i = 0, ilen = myarray.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        document.write('<input name="' + myarray[i] + '"/>');
    }
```